# Array filter for flatlist, filterdFaqs is not defined

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am trying to filter an array

Data:

```
0: {question: "xx", answer: "<p>xx</p>", userToDisplayFor: "LiteUsers"}
1: {question: "x", answer: "<p>xx</p>", userToDisplayFor: "LiteUsers"},...
```

I get **filterdFaqs is not defined**, any ideas?

```
export const Faq = ({ navigation }) => {
    const {
        faq,
        userTypeReducer: { userType },
    } = useSelector((state) => state);

    const { data, loading, error } = faq;

    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    const goBack = () => {
        ...
    };

    useMountEffect(() => {
        trackScreen(screens.FAQ);
        dispatch(FaqList());
    }, []);

    if (userType == "Lite") {
        const filterdFaqs = data.filter((q) => q.userToDisplayFor == "LiteUsers");
    } else {
        const filterdFaqs = data.filter((q) => q.userToDisplayFor !== "LiteUsers");
    }

    console.log(filterdFaqs);

    return (
        ...
            <FlatList
                ...
                data={filterdFaqs}
                renderItem={...}
            />
       ..
    );
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `const` inside of any block, it only exists in that block:

```js
{
    const foo = 'bar';
}

console.log(foo);
```

So what you need to do is declare `filterdFaqs` outside of the `if`:

```
let filterdFaqs;

if (userType == "Lite") {
    filterdFaqs = data.filter((q) => q.userToDisplayFor == "LiteUsers");
} else {
    filterdFaqs = data.filter((q) => q.userToDisplayFor !== "LiteUsers");
}
```

or inline the if:

```
const filterdFaqs = userType === "Lite" ? data.filter((q) => q.userToDisplayFor == "LiteUsers") : data.filter((q) => q.userToDisplayFor !== "LiteUsers");
```

Comment: filterdFaqs is populated, but then the page rerenders and I get `Cannot read property 'filter' of null`

Comment: That is because your initial state for `faq` (before `dispatch(FaqList());` completes) doesn't contain a `data` key.  Either set the initial state better, or change `data.filter` to `(data || []).filter`